# Custom path cap on a Vector Drawable?

Tags: android, android-vectordrawable, animatedvectordrawable

Is it possible to have a custom cap at the end of a path of on a vector drawable [like an SVG Marker](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/marker)?

If not, is there a way to find the location of the end of the path from the Vector Drawable so I can draw it myself?

The vector drawable will be animated by trimming its path, so the value will be dynamic.

Example below:

[image: custom path example]

Comment: The pathdata should be there for you to read e.g. android:pathData="M300,70 l 0,-70 70,70 0,0 -70,70z" so you can do what you want with it.

Comment: I'm animating along the path, so I would need the marker to follow the `trimPathEnd` attribute, not just the path as it's given in the Vector Drawable